# Forward Remote_addr across Apache and OHS

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers

I am attempting a hosting site with weblogic listening behine OHS and Apache. 
I am able to retain the remote_addr on apache using remote_ip but not able to carry it forward to OHS.

I can share configurations, the remote_addr on the OHS displays the loopback address.

looking for more information. Any direction would help :) at this moment.

Many Thanks.
Sk

Comment: Just to clarify, Apache is running as a reverse proxy for OHS?

Comment: Yes. Apache in a reverse proxy for OHS.

Comment: Got a perl script. That need to be added. The script was specific to perl version 1, i had to rework that to version 5.